# Reading serial data in real time using Qt Designer interface in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, pyserial, uart

I am trying to read data from my Uart port in real time using an interface developped in Python. For that i am sending repeatedly my command and reading after 500ms the MCU response.
However, what i did isn't working. Using threads the function that reads the data in real time doesn't show me the results unless the thread is finished. Can you please help?

PS: i know that the code isn't really that clean.

**this is the reading function**

```
def uart_read_data_permanently(self, mesurementbox):
    """
    Reads permanently the Data received from the host controller to the PC
    :return: None
    """
    serial_connect.flush()  # it is buffering. required to get the data out
    answer = ""
    while True:
        serial_connect.write(("getCurrent" + '\n').encode("utf-8"))
        time.sleep(0.5)
        answer += serial_connect.readline().decode("utf-8")
        print(answer)
        mesurementbox.mesurements_textedit.append(f'>> Scanning results: {answer}' + '\n')
```

**and this is the uart connect function in which i create my thread:**
*The command i need to send is "getcurrent"*

```
def uart_send_data(self):
    """
    Sends a command via UART from the PC to the host controller
    and waits for a response
    :return: None
    """
    cmd_name = self.cmd_combo.currentText()
    cmd_name = cmd_name.strip()
    if cmd_name in cmd_list:
        if cmd_name == "version":
            cmd_parameter = self.cmd_parameters_combo.currentText()
            if cmd_parameter in cmd_parameters_list:
                serial_connect.write((cmd_name + '\n' + cmd_parameter + '\n').encode())
                self.console.append(f'>> Sending command {cmd_name} for {cmd_parameter}')
            else:
                self.console.append(f'>> Sending command')
                self.console.append(f'Missing configuration')
                self.console.append(f'Please select a valid command and parameter')
                return
            time.sleep(0.1)
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.uart_read_data)
            t1.daemon = True
            t1.start()
        elif cmd_name == "getCurrent":
            self.console.append(f'>> Sending command "{cmd_name}"')
            ui_mesurements = mesurementsDialog()
            ui_mesurements.setupUi(mesurements)
            mesurements.show()
            t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.uart_read_data_permanently(ui_mesurements))
            t2.daemon = True
            t2.start()
        else:
            serial_connect.write((cmd_name + '\n').encode("utf-8"))
            self.console.append(f'>> Sending command "{cmd_name}"')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.uart_read_data)
            t1.daemon = True
            t1.start()
    else:
        self.console.append(f'>> {cmd_name} Unknown. Please select a valid command')
```

Comment: I made a little gui program a while ago that sounds like it does something very similar. The code's real messy, but it works fairly consistently. https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=22&t=20775

Comment: You have no RTOS running and Python is completely not suitable for RT tasks. So, what do you expect to achieve then?

Answer (score 0):

for those who are concerned or are facing the same issue as the one i faced. the answer is:
Check out **QTimer**